# CSS and Layout Issues in codenameone

Tags: css, codenameone

Point 1. The image shows the simulator with the title in black letters. In the next section of the image it shows what is configured in the CSS and finally its application in the inspector. I tried assigning other UIIDs in the inspector and it changes everything except the color of the letters.

[image]

My CSS mapping code.

```
public class Tarifa extends Form {
Idioma idioma;

public Tarifa() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setScrollable(true);
    Usuario iU = Usuario.getInstancia();
    idioma = new Idioma(iU.getIdioma());
    this.setTitle(idioma.getMensaje2());
    this.getToolbar().setUIID("Titulo");
}
```

}

In point 2 I need to place the icons as close to the right of the form and therefore the search fields grow but I can't make it happen.

My code in that case is:

```
        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("ButtonUtil");
    // Contenedor de Lugar de Inicio
    Button btInicio = new Button(idioma.getMensaje5(), FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_FLAG, s, 4), "ButtonBusqueda");
    Button btLocalizar = new Button(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LOCATION_PIN, s, 4));
    Container cnInicio1 = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    cnInicio1.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, btInicio);
    cnInicio1.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, btLocalizar);

    Container cnInicio = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    cnInicio.addComponent(new Label(idioma.getMensaje5()));
    cnInicio.addComponent(cnInicio1);
```

My CSS is:

```
    ButtonBusqueda {
font-family: "native:MainRegular";
font-size: 2.5mm;
color: blue;
text-align: left;
border: 1pt solid gray;
padding: 1mm;
margin-left: 1mm;
margin-top: 1mm;
```

}

```
ButtonUtil {
font-family: "native:MainRegular";
font-size: 3mm;
color: blue;
text-align: left;
margin: 0mm;
paddin: 0mm;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are customizing the container surrounding the title (the title area). Unlike normal CSS properties aren't inherited directly in our CSS. We have explicit hierarchies and the title (which you can see is below the renamed UIID) inherits its styles from Label.

Using this style should let you customize the title font:

```css
Title {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but point 2?

Comment: I'm guessing that what you're seeing there is the 2mm on each side for the padding and margin. You can highlight the entry in the inspector which will mark its bounds. It will also show you its size in pixels which you can compare to the size of the form to see where pixels went missing. It will also show you the padding and margin applied in pixels.